# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions very masive memory disaster

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiwebview

I have this line of code to take screenshot of uiview:

```
    - (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIImage *viewImage = nil;
    float height;
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        height = view.frame.size.height;
    }else{
        height = 730;
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, height), YES, 0.0);

        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, -60, view.bounds.size.width, height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

... in this uiview is UIWebView.

This `- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view` method I call in everytime uiwebview finish load. And there's is my problem: When I open some small webpages like google it method takes some kb of memory, but when I open something biger like bbc, cnn, yahoo or stackoverflow, it can take up to 80mb memory usage.

There is snapshoot of instrument when cnn.com was opened.
[image]
After few seconds it realeses, but I don't want that big memory usage, because you might imagine, how useless becomes uiwebview in these seconds.

So, what is your suggestions, how to take screenshoot of uiwebview, without so big memory usage, I don't even need this `uiimage` in good quality, because I put it in 120*80 `uiimageview` in one of the screen corners.

Comment: That's because the contentSize is bigger than the frame, try to use the frame size instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last parameter in  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is scale. If you know you only need a low resolution rendering of the web view, try setting a value for scale less than 1.0.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, height), YES, 0.2);
```